# NetPlan bridge doesn't work 18.04

Tags: networking, server, netplan, network-bridge, lxd

I am trying to setup network bridge on 18.04 VPS with 2 IPs and right after applying `netplan apply`, internet stops working while all configuration and adresses are good: `ip -c addr` and `ifconfig` shows no ip on ens18, but correct IPs, gateways and broadcast on br0.

My netplan config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      match:
        macaddress: 00:50:56:3e:23:56
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [ens18]
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: 
        - IP1/24
        - IP2/24
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: IP1_GATEWAY
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: IP2_GATEWAY
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      parameters:
        stp: false
        forward-delay: 0
```

Working configuration: 
[ip -c addr](https://gist.github.com/grig191/778c3ebd14351aa3c0a7e698f9363ea3)
Not working (with bridge): [ip -c addr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv5X6.png)

Point of this is to setup one LXC container with second IP
Thank you for your help

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *netplan*`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this make sense...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:50:56:3e:23:56
      addresses: [IP1/24]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: IP1_GATEWAY
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
        search: []
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [ens18]
      addresses: [IP2/24]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: IP2_GATEWAY
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
        search: []
      parameters:
        stp: false
        forward-delay: 0
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # make config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply new configuration

`reboot` # reboot and verify proper operation

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95060/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-netplan-bridge-doesnt-work-18-04).